# Basic cardinal arithmetic without choice

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, cardinal-arithmetic

Do we know everything about addition and multiplication of cardinalities in choiceless set theory?

For example, let $M$ be a model of $\textsf{ZF}+\textsf{AD}+V=L(\mathbb{R})$, consider the sets $\mathbb{R}$, $\omega_1$, and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ as interpreted in $M$ (feel free to add more in case this turns out to be trivial), and then consider the "semi-rng" generated by these sets under disjoint union and Cartesian product, modulo equinumerosity in $M$. Can we compute the structure of this semi-rng? Is there any $M\models\textsf{ZF}$ that produces a "freest" semi-rng?

Comment: Woodin's paper *The cardinals below $|[\omega_1]^{<\omega_1}|$* seems relevant to your question.

Comment: You can have models of ZF in which every partial order emebds into the cardinals, and so there always large sets of pairwise incomparable cardinals. It seems to me that those will have a very crazy structure of arithmetic. But as a whole I'm not sure what is your actual question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If we only consider, e.g., finitely many parameter-free definable sets (instead of arbitrary sets), can the semi rng they generate be simply described? At first I was hoping that the structure generated by $\mathbb{R}$ and $\omega_1$ is "the symmetric algebra of the monoid $\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R},\omega_1,\mathbb{R}+\omega_1\}$", but that's far from true. But it still seems interesting if given two sets $A,B$ there is an algorithm to figure out whether they generate a symmetric algebra. And I'm more interested in determinacy model than arbitrary $\mathsf{ZF}$ model

Comment: @AsafKaragila But my last question does concern arbitrary $\mathsf{ZF}$ models. An attempt to formalize it: fix a bunch of definitions of cardinalities, modulo provable equinumerosity in $\mathsf{ZF}$; for each model $M$ there is an homomorphism from those definitions to actual cardinalities in $M$; is there an $M$ that is universal, namely all other homomorphisms factor through it

Comment: @newaccount You almost never get universality in such a sense when you're working with definitions in a logic as strong as first-order logic; consider definitions like "$0$ if $\mathsf{AC}$ and $1$ if $\neg \mathsf{AC}$." No model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ can simultaneously separate this from both $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @HanulJeon That paper and its references mention Borel equivalence relations a lot. Is it true that under determinacy axioms $E$ reduces to $E'$ iff there is an injective set map from $X/E$ to $Y/E'$? If not, how exactly is Borel cardinality related to true cardinality?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know.